# Add Linear Layout view dynamically in eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-linearlayout, eclipse-adt

How can I add view (with linear layout id/linearlayout_tambahkeluhan can add automatically when I click button id/tambah_keluhan) in case that...the content in linearlayout_tambahkeluhan is id/layout_keluhan, id/layout_status, id/layout_tindakan...How the code in Java? anyone can help me? Thx before

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_tambahkeluhan"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/layout_keluhan" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView11"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:text="KELUHAN"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView12"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:text=":"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner_keluhan"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="4" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/layout_status" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView13"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:text="STATUS"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView14"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:text=":"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner_status"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="4" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/layout_tindakan" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView15"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:text="TINDAKAN"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView16"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:text=":"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/editText_tindakan"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="4"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_tambahkeluhan"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:text="tambah keluhan"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:textStyle="italic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You try addView(View view) function) with view can be controls or xml layout.
Example: `((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_tambahkeluhan)).addView(btnNew);`

Comment: What view you want to add when you click button? addView(View view) work ok with me. I don't understand you purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your linearLayout visibility 'gone' like this:

```
             <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_tambahkeluhan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:visibility="gone">
```

Then in onCreate function in your Activity do this:

```
LinearLayout yourLinearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_tambahkeluhan);    
Button yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_tambahkeluhan);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    yourLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.Visible);
}
}
```

Comment: it can't works
but i want to add more the layout..not to show/hide the layout?
can you help me to think the code?
thx